# Cordova hook and access to build settings

Tags: android, ios, cordova, build, hook

During a hook for Cordova
on for example **before_build/before_prepare**:

```
cordova build
-> before prepare hook
-> prepare
-> after prepare hook
-> before build hook
-> build
-> after build hook
```

Is it possible to obtain settings about the build? If it's a release build or a development build, if the current platform is 'ios' or 'android' or anything else for that matter.

Is this at all possible?

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is possible exactly like mentioned in the [documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/appdev/hooks/index.html#javascript). Your hook(-function) gets passed a `context` object which contains all the information you need. Example `context`:

```
{
  "hook": "before_plugin_install",
  "scriptLocation": "c:\\script\\full\\path\\appBeforePluginInstall.js",
  "cmdLine": "The\\exact\\command\\cordova\\run\\with arguments",
  "opts": {
    "projectRoot":"C:\\path\\to\\the\\project",
    "cordova": {
      "platforms": ["android"],
      "plugins": ["plugin-withhooks"],
      "version": "0.21.7-dev"
    },
    "plugin": {
      "id": "plugin-withhooks",
      "pluginInfo": {
        ...
      },
      "platform": "android",
      "dir": "C:\\path\\to\\the\\project\\plugins\\plugin-withhooks"
    }
  },
  "cordova": {...}
}
```

Especially the `cmdLine` property will be of interest for you to check if a `--release` flag was passed and to detect which platform was built.

Comment: I was looking for the --prod flag, but strangely, I got only the release flag. My command is `ionic cordova build android --prod --release` and my cmdLine is `'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node.exe C:\\Users\\username*\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\cordova\\bin\\cordova build android --release'`.

Comment: Found that by using Ionic, commands was rewritte. If someone has my issue, you need to use Ionic hooks => https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/configuration